# Run Android Daemon at Boot

Tags: android, c, android-source

I have written an executable in C for Android. It compiles and gets loaded into the device as expected in /system/bin. I can run it via the adb shell, and it works as expected. What I can't figure out is how to get it to run at boot. I added the following to init.rc:

```
service mydaemon /system/bin/mydaemon
    user root
    seclabel u:r:su:s0
    disabled
```

And also, under the "on boot" section, I added:

```
start mydaemon
```

The application does not start at boot, and nothing about it appears in the log when I try using logcat.

I've tried several different values for seclabel. I've tried declaring it as part of various classes, but nothing works. I've found a few suggestions online, but they were either not applicable (e.g. they used their own .rc file), or they were really old and no longer applicable.

Can someone tell me know to get my application to run at boot?

Comment: May be blocked by sepolicy rules. Find avc logs to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Yong, in the comment above, was correct. I needed to add a new sepolicy. See the following link for more:

https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy